# Is it more pythonic to close a function with return or through indentation?

Tags: python

If I have a function that does not need to return a variable, is it considered better coding practice to close the function like this:

```
def foo():
    """Code"""
    return
# More code
```

or like this?

```
def bar():
   """Code"""
# More code
```

Comment: Firstly - `def foo:` isn't valid syntax...

Comment: Have you checked PEP 8? http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @K.Brafford thanks, this is the first time I have seen this style guide.

Comment: @JonClements thanks, it is corrected

Comment: The PEP8 is definitely worth reading (and re-reading periodically)

Comment: @Phil your edit to foo() makes """Code"" the docstring and for bar() makes bar() invalid syntax again as it only has a docstring and not even a pass

Comment: @JonClements well that's what I thought too at first, but my interpreter doesn't complain. Is it actually invalid?

Comment: @Phil I apologise - it's valid syntax... - I didn't realise just having a docstring worked (although it's practically useless :)) - learn something new everyday I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd only use bare return for an early exit from the function. At the end of a function it leaves me wondering if you meant to return something and forgot to finish.

Answer (score 4):

I think leaving out the return statement is the most pythonic thing to do. It makes it clear that the function wasn't designed to return anything and, more importantly, I think it just looks better.

```
def hello():
    print 'hello world'
```

versus

```
def hello():
    print 'hello world'
    return
```

Comment: I'd only use return None if the function normally returned an object instance or something.

Comment: well... `none` is something... or is it?

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I agree. It's probably best to leave the statement out altogether. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly`return None` when your function is mutating something else (eg. do_something_to_something()), or is an instance method of a class that mutates itself.

Make sure the behaviour is documented so it doesn't muck you/or anyone else up later though.